# Php Textbox data is not read

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am trying to get data from html form in php.
this is my html code.

```
<div id="search_specify">
    <?php echo form_open('search/advanced_search');?>
        <a class="srch_heading">Keyword</a>
        <input name="key" class="srch_box" type="text" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <a class="srch_heading">First Name</a>
        <input name="first" class="srch_box" type="text" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <a class="srch_heading">Last Name</a>
        <input name="last" class="srch_box" type="text"/>
        <br />
        <br />
        <a class="srch_heading">Company</a>
        <input name="company" class="srch_box" type="text"/>
        <br />
        <br />
        <a class="srch_heading">Country</a><br />
        <select name="country" class="slct_box"/>
            <option>aaa</option>
        </select>
    <?php echo form_submit('submit','Search') ?>
</div>
```

this is my php code

```
$key=$_POST['key'];
$first=$_POST['first'];
$last=$_POST['last'];
$company=$_POST['company'];
$country=$_POST['country'];

echo $first;
echo $last;
echo $company;
echo $key;
echo$country;
```

the values of key, company and country are read fine but the code did not get the value of first and last

This the the page source code

```
<form action="http://localhost/ok/index.php/search/advanced_search" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"><a class="srch_heading">Keyword</a>
    <input name="key" class="srch_box" type="text" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <a class="srch_heading">First Name</a>
    <input name="first" class="srch_box" type="text" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <a class="srch_heading">Last Name</a>
    <input name="last" class="srch_box" type="text"/>
    <br />
    <br />
    <a class="srch_heading">Company</a>
    <input name="company" class="srch_box" type="text"/>
    <br />
    <br />
    <a class="srch_heading">Country</a><br />
    <select name="country" class="slct_box"/>
        <option>aaa</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"/></div>
</form>
```

Please help

Comment: There's no reason why the code as shown wouldn't work, so the problem must be in code that you haven't shown.

Comment: Is the `HTML` code wrapped in a `<form>` element?

Comment: The code for them is fine, so its nothing to do with this code. Show where you are outputting the data.

Comment: @byf-ferdy You can see that he is echoing a form open and close tag using HTML helper methods. Obviously that does not mean those methods are outputting the correct HTML.

Comment: Just to be sure, did you enter some text in first and last text fields? And, **how** did you come to the decision that first and last did not get values? I mean, what php function did you use to check?

Comment: @SSMA Can you view the source of the generated webpage and paste what it looks like, complete with the form tags?

Comment: @BadHorsie: `form_close` is missing, not big deal though for this question.

Comment: I use echo to check values.
all the values are echoed as expected other than first and last

Comment: <?php form_close(); ?> is missing try to fix it

Comment: Try `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: Thanks all!
the problem is solved by adding <?php echo form_close();?> after submit.

Comment: @SarwarErfan Turned out to be a big deal lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not closing the form. That was causing the trouble. So i added `<?php echo form_close();?>` after `<?php echo form_submit('submit','Search') ?>` And problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code in you php file.

```
echo $this->input->post('first');
```

It will give your all post data.